# Trim String with Given Character in mule 4 dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Hi all I got a situation on Trimming the String ends or starts with specific characters in Mule 4

eg:

```
string = "\/Hello World!\/Location\/"
Characters = "\/"
```

Output:

```
result = "Hello World!\/Location"
```

and in mule 4 In built trim only accepting String and removes only spaces on starting, ending of the String

is there any built in function that can solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this Function it may work but if any inbuit function availiabe please let me know

```
fun trim(str:String,chr:String = " ",size : Number = -1 )= 
do
{
    var siz= if(size == -1) sizeOf(str) else size
    var fs=str[(if(str startsWith chr) sizeOf(chr) else 0) to -1] default ""
    var bs=fs[0 to -( if(str endsWith chr) sizeOf(chr) + 1 else 1)] default ""
    var newsize=sizeOf(bs)
---
if(newsize == siz) bs else trim(bs,chr,newsize)
}
var string = "\/Hello World!\/Location\/"
var Characters = "\/"
---
trim(string,Characters)
```